# Transfer around 1000 audio files at a time to Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0

Tags: bluetooth, tablet

I need to transfer around 1000 audio files at a time from my laptop to my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0.

It's asking for permission every time for each file. Are there any settings that'd allow me to transfer all files at once? I don't find any settings on my tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), you will get the `adb` executable in `/platform-tools/adb`.

With it, you can push an unlimited number of files directly to your Android device from a command line, e.g. in Bash, once your tablet is connected to the computer via USB:

```
for i in *.mp3; do adb push "$i" /mnt/sdcard/some/place/; done
```

Note that you might have to enable USB debugging from your tablet's preferences for this to work.

Comment: Knowing your operating system and the specifics of what you want to transfer where would help though.

Answer (score 1):

A less technical approach would be to:

1. Zip them up
2. Email them to an account on the Tab
3. Extract them using an app like [Androzip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource&hl=en) or [ASTRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en)